# SHA256 Algorithm in Turbo C not able to compile

Tags: c, algorithm, sha256, turbo-c

I am trying to run the SHA256 algorithm in c which is given on wesite

[Koders Code Search][2]

For that I am using Turbo C Compilar on windows machine and it is installed on with directory path set to

```
1 C:\Program Files\TC\    
2 C:\Program Files\TC\INCLUDE
3 C:\Program Files\TC\lib
```

I kept all the header files in 3

```
C:\Program Files\TC\INCLUDE
```

folder
which are required to run this `SHA256.c` file.
Whenever i try to compile the code then setupd gives error saying

```
Illegle file name SHA256.exe and 3 SHA256.obj.
```

I m not able to find out the root cause why I m getting this error, what mistake I m doing.

[image: Error Image which I am facing]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to get a more up-to-date C compiler - Turbo C is 30 years old, non-standard, obsolete and unsupported.

Comment: Agree with @Paul R, what about eclipse CDT, netbeans, dev-cpp or even Visual Studio express?? all of them are free up-to-date and supported.

Comment: It might be that Turbo C can't handle long filenames, or filenames/paths with spaces in them.

Comment: Actually I tried this with Helios CDT but dont know how to compile c programmes in Eclipse.It says binary file missing.I dont understand what exactly settting need to be done.
Launch failed binary file missing.

Comment: Even though India is physically connected to the rest of the world, there seems to be some invisible barrier that stops all under-21 compilers from coming in...

Answer (score 1):

Turbo C is an old DOS application. As such it doesn't work with long file and directory names. Long as in, longer than 8 characters in the name and 3 characters in the extension. So, 12345678.txt would be OK, but 123456789.txt or 12345678.html would not.

You really want to move the `TC` directory out of `C:\Program Files` to `C:\` or `C:\Project` and name all your files and directories that Turbo C (and your programs compiled with it) will access having in mind the 8.3 limitation described above.

Oh, and there should be no funky characters in 8.3 names, no spaces, non-English letters, etc etc. Use only English letters, numbers and underscores (pretty much like in C itself).

Remember to update the `PATH` environment variable and any path settings in Turbo C IDE to reflect the new location.

Also, it's a bad practice to put your project files into the directories, where the compiler stores its header files, any of its files for that matter.